# How to create sub accounts for my clients in my DocuSign account, and subscribe on behalf of my client via API?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a system in which I am integrating the DocuSign API.

Inside my system my client can send a document to the emails that it defined.

I have a DocuSign account with the Integration Key enabled on my system, how do I register within my account the subaccounts for each of my clients to send their contracts to their clients using the API?

I have already tested the entire Docusign API, I just can not find how to register sub-accounts to send on behalf of each client of mine!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Stack Overflow is not customer support for <your favourite company>](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746). If you read the [tag:docusignapi] tag wiki, it suggests you ask these sorts of questions at the [DocuSign Community](//support.docusign.com/community/).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not too clear. Hopefully this will be of help:

DocuSign does not have "subaccounts."

DocuSign has `organizations` (which group together an organization's or company's `accounts`).

Customers often have multiple accounts, with or without the organization capability. Accounts have account-wide settings. So it is common that the HR and Finance departments will have separate accounts, with different settings.

Accounts have one or more `members` (users). An individual can be a member of more than one account.

An `Integration Key` (also called a `client_id`) identifies an application.

An Integration Key (and its app) can be used by any user on any account. The user must give permission for the application to act on his/her behalf.

DocuSign has a developer sandbox (called `demo`) and multiple production systems (Europe, North America 1, 2, 3, etc). The Integration Keys in demo are entirely separate from those in the production systems.

The ["Go-live" process](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live) is used to copy an Integration Key from demo to the production systems.

Comment: I contacted Docusign, they told me how to integrate with API.

I needed my application to sign on behalf of my clients, I registered every client on my system as a user in my Docusign account.

To perform actions via API on behalf of my clients, I can not use oAlth authentication with Authorization token, I must use X-DocuSign-Authentication.

I made the changes and my integration worked!

Thank you.

Comment: X-DocuSign-Authentication (Legacy Header) is not recommended by DocuSign [DS Docs]  (https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html), you should use User Authorization Code Grant (OAUTH)